# When did static electricity become a common occurrence?

Tags: everyday-life

I was wondering if there are references to static electricity in any classic works.
 I understand There were many people experimenting with it over the millennia, but was it also a common household occurrence? You know, wear certain clothes, touch a certain metal, and Zap!

Someone claimed that static electricity only became a common occurrence after synthetic material became widespread which aids in helping the charge. I have not found any helpful leads researching this online.

Is there documentation regarding any of this?

Comment: Das ist irrelevant on this forum.

Comment: Which are you asking? Whether static electricity was common prior to synthetics, or when static electricity was first described in a historical document? Very different questions.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace How would we know if it was common or not if there was no documentation? I want to know if it occurred at all and if it was as common as it is today.

Comment: Static electricity existed prior to the human presence on the planet.  There are experimental records of people producing static electricity - those might indicate that it was uncommon but reproducible. Then there is the thesis that it was uncommon before synthetics; that is a different question.

Comment: @Mark I was under the impression that people posting questions on this forum were encouraged to put as much information on the subject they are seeking into the body of the question. I'm not sure why any of the ideas I mentioned are distracting from the main objective.

Comment: How long have people kept cats as pets, and stroked them?

Comment: @jamesqf that's partially why I'm not buying into the fact that it's a recent evolution of the textile industry. Fur has been around people for a long long time. I'm just looking for some written acknowledgment of the phenomenon.

Comment: Rubbing cat's fur on amber is an old, well-known way to generate a spark of static electricity.  Both have been used by humans for thousands of years.

Comment: @Pieter True. That would qualify as a controlled scientific experiment. I'm trying to find out if it was a common household occurrence. Like when I take off my coat and grab a hanger and get zapped.

Comment: I think the limiting factor would have been metal, not synthetic fabrics.  Wool clothing and furry cats have been around for thousands of years, but metal doorknobs and faucets are a much more recent invention.

Answer (score 1):

The first verifiable mention I could find was in Theophrastus (circa 300 BC):

> [Lyngourion] has the power of attraction, just as amber has, and some
>   say that it not only attracts straws and bits of wood, but also copper
>   and iron, if the pieces are this, as Diokles used to explain. --
>   Theophrastus

Comment: +1 for your time and effort, but this is not what I am looking for. I am looking for reference as a common occurrence, not as a scientific experiment. Ty again though.

Comment: @user6591: I think the problem might be that it was both too common and too insignificant to be written down.

Comment: @user6591 Getting zapped by static electricity was not a "common occurrence" until synthetic fibers were developed in the 1950s.

Comment: @Tyler That was one of the theories mentioned in the question. See in the comments for a rejection of this assertion based on the availability of animal fur.

Comment: @user6591 That is not right, animal fur will not normally develop enough electricity to deliver a painful shock.

Comment: @Tyler that is a sound theory. I am looking for any references that prove or disprove that.

Comment: @user6591 You do need a "reference" to prove that, you just need a cat.

Comment: @Tyler and possibly Amber. Again, I'm trying not to stick my head between the two apparent sides of this argument of how common it was that's running in the comments. I'm just curious about it's being referenced as a common occurrence or not.